# Missing filed type error strange after upgrade flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, type-declaration

After I upgraded flutter from v1.0.0 to 1.7.8_hotfix+4, there are a lot of errors those never showed before.
I can declare variable like:

`var caption;`

or it will show

`Missing field type for 'caption', Try adding an explict type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file.'`

I have to change  `var caption;`  to `dynamic caption;`

Is it related to analysis_options.yaml?
I tried to copy v1.0.0 's analysis_options.yaml seems it still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

i got error too after upgrade flutter,
for me, its because unstable internet.

so, i download manual flutter from https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases. Then replace it with the new one from download.